# Concat and drop columns function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, drop

I normally use the common python codes to concat a few columns and drop the rest. But when I try to create it in a function (def), it doesn’t work. And I am pretty sure that I’m not doing it in the correct way. Can anyone support with this please?

```
def prepocessor_concat():
    df[‘1’] = df[‘2’] + df[‘3’] + [‘4’]
    df.drop([‘2’, ‘3’, ‘4’,],    axis=1, inplace=True
```

Comment: you have to pass the df and return it

Comment: or define the function in a way you can use pandas `apply`

Comment: Also, if you `pop('2')` instead of `df['2']` you won't have to `drop` later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned "concatenation", but your
intent seems to be focused on "addition".
This function demonstrates both operations.

```
df_example = pd.DataFrame([
        {"2":  6,  "3":  7,  "4":  8,  "5":  9},
        {"2": 16,  "3": 17,  "4": 18,  "5": 19},
])

def preprocessor_concat(df):
    print(pd.concat([df["2"], df["3"], df["4"]], axis="rows"))
    print("\n")
    df["1"] = df_example.pop("2") + df_example.pop("3") + df_example.pop("4")
    print(df)

preprocessor_concat(df_example)
```

output

```
0     6
1    16
0     7
1    17
0     8
1    18
dtype: int64

    5   1
0   9  21
1  19  51
```

Notice that the shape of the row concatenation result is different
from the original dataframe shape.
You will need compatible shapes across all columns.
Or do what we see above: produce a brand *new* dataframe.

Comment: The first row in my code is to concatenate the columns and the second row is to drop the columns. I’m trying to create these 2 steps within 1 function. Can I use your code in a function as well? But the code to drop the columns is missing in your example.

Comment: It’s working perfectly fine!! What if I want to drop 2 more columns (imagine they’re called ‘5’ and ‘6’. Can I use the same code with ‘df.pop’ and paste it in the same function?

Comment: Those three `.pop()` calls say "use it **and** drop it" as one operation. But you know, the `.drop()` operation is pretty versatile, and can be used at _any_ time that you're tired of keeping a column around.  Here's a brief excerpt from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html): `df = df.drop(columns=['B', 'C'])`